# How to remove all rows that don't meet all conditions (per group)?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Just to start, sorry if this question has been asked before (I'm sure it has, I just can't find the right answer)

Let's say I have the following data frame. In this case, the runner Tim got injured in the second lap. What I want to do is to remove lap #2 from all the runners since his data can't be compared anymore.

```
race <- data.frame("Runner" = c("John","John","Elsa","Elsa","Tim","Tim"),
                "Time" = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA),
                "Lap" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
                )
> race
  Runner Time Lap
1   John    1   1
2   John    2   2
3   Elsa    3   1
4   Elsa    4   2
5    Tim    5   1
6    Tim   NA   2
```

So basically what I want to end with is with a data frame with 3 rows. One for John, Elsa and Tim, each row with the time from lap #1.

I enjoy working with the tidyverse, so if there is an answer that uses the dplyr or anything like that then I would really appreciate.

Comment: try `race[race$Lap == 1, ]`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Sorry for not adding in the original post that I want the code to work also on other data sets. I do know that I could use filter with Lap == 1,  or subset with base R, but this won't work with larger data sets with a lot more runners, laps, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safer approach would be to find first `Lap` when anybody got injured (`NA` in `Time`) and then remove all the data from that `Lap` onwards

```
subset(race[order(race$Lap), ], Lap < Lap[which.max(is.na(Time))])


#  Runner Time Lap
#1   John    1   1
#2   Elsa    3   1
#3    Tim    5   1
```

and with `dplyr` that would be

```
library(dplyr)

race %>%
 arrange(Lap) %>%
 filter(Lap < Lap[which.max(is.na(Time))])
```

This first arranges the data by `Lap`, `which.max(is.na(Time)` finds out the index where first `NA` was encountered , we take the corresponding `Lap` and keep all rows lesser than that `Lap`.

This would still work if you have 10 `Lap`s in your dataset and some player got injured in 6th `Lap`.

Comment: This is actually a great answer. I just tried it with a larger data set but yeah it makes complete sense. Now I feel dumb for not thinking like you did. I tried grouping by Runner and other stuff that took me nowhere, but your approach was a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
race <- race%>%
  filter(Lap == 1)
```

Comment: @DarrenTsai tottaly true, no need, force of habit i guess. editing now.

Comment: By the way, added as answer because i can't post comments yet :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know that in this case I can just filter by selecting lap 1, but it would be good to get a code that would also work with larger data sets where it becomes very hard to just manually select a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it via base R. We split on `Runner` after we clean from NAs. We then `intersect` the `Lap` and keep only the ones found in that intersect, i.e.

```
race[race$Lap %in% Reduce(intersect, split(race$Lap[!is.na(race$Time)], race$Runner[!is.na(race$Time)])),]
#  Runner Time Lap
#1   John    1   1
#3   Elsa    3   1
#5    Tim    5   1
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried to use the intersect function but I couldn't make it work (well, at least not the way I wanted it to work). It makes sense though. I think the only issue is that it would be harder to use it in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

We can use also use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(race, Lap == 1)
```